# How to avoid having the layout jump when avoiding the keyboard with a bottom aligned View?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a View I want to position at the bottom of the screen with `position: absolute, bottom: 0`, and keep it just above the keyboard. I can't get this to work on Android without the layout breaking.

On iOS this was pretty easy with `react-native-reanimated`'s `useAnimatedKeyboard` doing the following:

```
const keyboard = useAnimatedKeyboard()

const bottomStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
  paddingBottom: keyboard.height.value,
}))
```

However, this breaks on Android, because I need to keep `android:windowSoftInputMode` set to `"adjustResize"` on the rest of the app, and when calling `useAnimatedKeyboard` this is modified, causing the app to shift slightly up for an instant, before the app readjusts to the new setting.

When I disabled this, I noticed the View would snap up to the keyboard for an instant, before shifting back to the bottom of the screen, on the first time the keyboard would open. On any other screen and any other time I did this again without closing the app, it would behave normally (stay at the bottom of the screen at all times, without shifting up). This was a problem because if I used the Keyboard event listener to watch for a `keyboardDidOpen` event to get the keyboard height, and use that as padding to the View, this would position the View correctly above the keyboard, but on the first time the keyboard was opened this would cause my View to appear an entire keyboard height above the keyboard for a moment, before settling back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to create this question so people in the future don't get stuck in the same issue I did.

Eventually, I was able to notice that there was a `KeyboardAvoidingView` on the render tree, but since it had `enabled` set to `false`, I didn't think that could be a problem.

However, what I noticed was that the `behavior` from that KeyboardAvoidingView was still impacting my component even though it was disabled. Therefore it wasn't enough to disable the `KeyboardAvoidingView`, but when I removed the `behavior` prop entirely, then this issue was resolved.

Therefore, the following would cause the bottom-aligned `View` to "jump" up for a moment, on the first time the keyboard was opened, before going back to the correct location:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView enabled={false} behavior="height">
{/* Rest of the screen */}
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

But this would make the `View` behave correctly from the first time the keyboard opened:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView enabled={false}>
{/* Rest of the screen */}
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```